# Немогу понять почему не работает смена префикса?

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
import random, string
import re
from random import choice
import time
import json
import requests
from itertools import cycle
import random
import os

def get_prefix(client, message): ##first we define get_prefix
    with open('/Users/Користувач/Desktop/Kiris/prefixes.json', 'r') as f: ##we open and read the prefixes.json, assuming it's in the same file
        prefixes = json.load(f) #load the json as prefixes
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] #recieve the prefix for the guild id given

    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix= (get_prefix),
    )
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild): #when the bot joins the guild
    with open('/Users/Користувач/Desktop/Kiris/prefixes.json', 'r') as f: #read the prefix.json file
        prefixes = json.load(f) #load the json file

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = 'bl!'#default prefix

    with open('/Users/Користувач/Desktop/Kiris/prefixes.json', 'w') as f: #write in the prefix.json "message.guild.id": "bl!"
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4) #the indent is to make everything look a bit neater

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild): #when the bot is removed from the guild
    with open('/Users/Користувач/Desktop/Kiris/prefixes.json', 'r') as f: #read the file
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id)) #find the guild.id that bot was removed from

    with open('/Users/Користувач/Desktop/Kiris/prefixes.json', 'w') as f: #deletes the guild.id as well as its prefix
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def changeprefix(ctx, prefix = None): #command: bl!changeprefix ...
    with open('/Users/Користувач/Desktop/Kiris/prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('/Users/Користувач/Desktop/Kiris/prefixes.json', 'w') as f: #writes the new prefix into the .json
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'Prefix changed to: {prefix}') #confirms the prefix it's been changed to
#next step completely optional: changes bot nickname to also have prefix in the nickname
    name=f'{prefix}BotBot'
```

Ошибки что выдает консоль [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В тексте ошибки написано, что `json` не может считать json-объект из объекта типа `None`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вернуться назад по стеку вызовов, то можно увидеть, что ошибка впервые вызывается в строке `22`, функции `get_prefix()` вашего кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая строчка встречается у вас в каждой функции и будет вызывать ошибку всегда, потому что у вас объект `f` почему-то принимает значение `None`

```
with open('/Users/Користувач/Desktop/Kiris/prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
   prefixes = json.load(f)
```

---

Это может быть потому что неправильно указан путь к файлу *(вероятнее всего, должно быть так):*

```
# добавить букву раздела диска
C:/Users/Користувач/Desktop/Kiris/prefixes.json
```

Попробуйте вывести объект файла и посмотреть что он из себя представляет `print(f)`

---

Или вы можете воспользоваться функцией `json.loads()`, которая принимает на вход не объект файла, а строку. Тогда код будет выглядеть так

```
prefixes = json.loads(f.read())
```

И заодно позволит посмотреть, а удается ли вообще прочитать файл.